# Reduce redundant conditions all the way

Tags: equation-solving, logic

I would expect `Reduce[(b == 0) || (a == 0 && b == 0)]` to give `b==0` since the second argument of `Or` implies the first.  However, `Reduce` does not simplify this.  How can I perform such a simplification automatically?  (In my actual use case the `Or` has about 30 such arguments.)

Comment: Why not `Simplify[(b == 0) || (a == 0 && b == 0)]` or `BooleanMinimize[(b == 0) || (a == 0 && b == 0)]`?

Comment: Thank you @Artes.  I did not think of trying `Simplify` (and I did not know about `BooleanMinimize`).

Comment: @Artes, make an answer out of your comment so the question gets closed ;)

Comment: @ivbc If you want to close it, you are free to answer exploiting my suggestion.

Comment: Also `LogicalExpand`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either as Artes or Michael E2 suggested above, or [`BooleanConvert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanConvert.html)

So let me summarize:

```
x = (b == 0) || (a == 0 && b == 0)
BooleanConvert[x]
LogicalExpand[x]
Simplify[x]
BooleanMinimize[x]
```

> `b == 0`